# python - How to efficiently delete specified string in a big file?

Tags: python

Hi I have a file with this data structure.

```
for each 3073 bytes:
<1 x label><3072 x pixel>
...
<1 x label><3072 x pixel>
the lable is between 0~9
```

Now I need to write a python script to read the file and to check every 3073 byte. if label is "1" then delete this 3073 bytes(label and pixel)

```
ex: 2 <1st 3072 bytes> 1 <2nd 3072 bytes> 9 <3rd 3072 bytes>....
after run the script:
    output:  2 <1st 3072 bytes> 9 <3rd 3072 bytes>....
```

Now my solution is to

```
1. use loop check every 3073 bytes 
   if the label is 1:
       then put the index to buffer
2. make a new file
   loop each 3073 bytes
   if this 3073 bytes index is in the buffer
       then skip
```

but I found this is very inefficient. So Is there any other smarter solution?

Comment: Why don't you show us your Python code? The devil is in the details. An algorithm might look fine in pseudo-code but be very ineffeciently written in Python.

Comment: Because I haven't write it down yet. Just tryna find a good solution before I write down the code....

Comment: How can you know it's very inefficient then? How big is your file?

Comment: 50000 * 3073 bytes. Because I'm trying to find a way that I don't have to new a file. just simply delete the string and continue to check for label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be reasonably fast (a few seconds at most for a 150MB file) and would never hold much data in memory :

```
chunk_size = 3072

with open('newpixels.bin', 'wb') as new_file:
    with open('pixels.bin', 'rb') as data:
        while True:
            label_and_pixels = data.read(1+chunk_size)
            if not label_and_pixels:
                break
            elif label_and_pixels[0] != '1':
                new_file.write(label_and_pixels)
```

With `pixels.bin` as input :

> 1XXX2YYY2ZZZ3AAA1BBB2CCC

and `chunk_size` set to `3`, it outputs :

> 2YYY2ZZZ3AAA2CCC

If you're sure that the algorithm is correct and the output data is fine, you could delete `'pixels.bin'` and rename `'newpixels.bin'` to `'pixels.bin'` at the end of your script.

Comment: just found that even 50000 data is not called big.. run so fast.

Comment: 150MB is peanuts for Python on any hardware that is less than 15 years old.

Answer (score 0):

the following algorithm might be a bit better:

```
1. use loop to check all 3073 bytes
   if the label is 1:
       continue
   else:
       write byte to new file (?)
```

Comment: Is there any other solution that I don't need a new file and directly delete the line?